# How to check if a polynomial is inside an ideal using a Groebner basis

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, groebner-basis

I'm given that an ideal $I=\langle F_1, F_2, F_3, F_4, F_5, F_6, F_7\rangle$

$F_1=a+b+c-d-e-f$

$F_2=a+b+c-g-h-i$

$F_3=a+b+c-g-e-c$

$F_4=a+b+c-a-e-i$

$F_5=a+d+g-a-e-i$

$F_6=a+d+g-c-f-i$

$F_7=a+d+g-b-e-h$

I've computed the Groebner Basis as $\{3f-4g-h+2i, e-f+g-i, d-f+2g-2i, c+f-g-h, b+f-2g, a+f-2g-h+i\}$

How can I use this result to determine if a given polynomial $F$ is in $I$

Comment: $F\in I$ iff the remainder of $F$ on the division by $G_1,\dots,G_6$ is zero, where $G_i$ are the polynomials of Grobner basis. (If you do the same for $F_1,\dots, F_7$ then you can have the surprise that $F\in I$ but the remainder is not zero.)

Comment: division by $F_1,...,F_7$ or division by the Groebner basis I mentioned

Comment: If the remainder on the division by $F_1,\dots,F_7$ is zero, then certainly $F\in I$, but it can happen that $F\in I$ and the remainder by $F_1,\dots,F_7$ is not zero. This is why one uses a Grobner bases, since for them such a strange phenomenon can't occur.

Comment: I changed $< F_1, F_2, F_3, F_4, F_5, F_6, F_7>$ to $\langle F_1, F_2, F_3, F_4, F_5, F_6, F_7\rangle$. That is standard usage. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It's worth noticing that for ideals $I$ generated by linear polynomials (homogenous of degree $1$) a linear polynomials belongs to $I$ if and only if it is a linear combination of the system of generators. Given a total ordering on the variables $\{a,b,c,\ldots\}$ a reduced Groebner basis is equivalent to "reduced row echelon form".